# What does object traverse mean in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to upload obj files into a WebGL scene using Three.js. I saw some sample codes like the one below which works great, but I want to know what does the command

```
object.traverse();
```

do? What will happen if we don't do traversing? Thank you.

```
// prepare loader and load the model
var oLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
oLoader.load('models/chair.obj', function(object, materials) {

// var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xa65e00 });

object.traverse( function(child) {
if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

  // apply custom material
  child.material = material2;

  // enable casting shadows
  child.castShadow = true;
  child.receiveShadow = true;
  }
  });

  object.position.x = 0;
 object.position.y = 0;
 object.position.z = 0;
 object.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
 lesson6.scene.add(object);
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is basically the iterator through your loaded object. You can pass the function to the traverse() function which will be called for every child of the object being traversed. If you call traverse() on scene. you traverse through the complete scene graph.

Comment: So, the way I get this is: the function written inside traverse argument will be applied to all the children of our object. Right? Now, just in order to make it clearer for myself, if we don't wanna use traverse feature, should we apply our function (the one written in traverse arguments) for each objects of the scene and merge all the results?

Comment: Will `object.traverse` be called on child of child? If not, what is the difference between calling `object.traverse` and `object.child.forEach`, or `for` loop?

Comment: @Halt Yes, `object.traverse` will be called on children of each child. Basically it traverses all the descendants of a any given three js object in Depth First Traversal manner.

Comment: @Harikrishna Thanks for ur help!